# How to change hostname for dynamic inventory?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am using `ec2.py` dynamic inventory to generate inventory. After the playbook is finished to run, the results are shown as list of IP addresses. It's clear that `ec2.py` can't tell me dns names for the hosts. However, in my playbook I am able to obtain dns names for each host. Question is how can I alter hostname for current host, so at the end I see dns name instead of IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `ec2.ini`, please find these parameters and uncomment if they didn't:

```
destination_variable = public_dns_name
hostname_variable = tag_Name
```

For detail, visit this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-devel/NbidWZo1GgE)